# select and print everything from a table except 1

Tags: php, mysql, select, echo

i have a question.
i have a table named news that has rows such as;

```
news_id ,   timestamp , login_id ,  headline,
```

i would like to echo all the headlines and timestamps that go with them except for login_id = 1

How can i achieve this?

i would like to do something like

```
select timestamp, headline, login_id;
echo everything exept login_id = 1;
```

printed on a table?

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT timestamp, headline, login_id FROM news WHERE login_id <> 1");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['timestamp'].' '.$row['headline'].' '.$row['login_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: How would i print this on a table? with headline timestamp and headline?

Comment: You can see Gaurav's response there.  Also, if you are wanting to format the timestamp (I'm not sure if your timestamp is really a timestamp or a date of some kind), you'll want to do something like date('m/d/Y', $row['timestamp']) to format it.  Check out the PHP date function for more on that.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT timestamp, headline, login_id FROM my_table WHERE login_id != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql query you would use is

```
SELECT timestamp
     , headline
     , login_id
  FROM news
 WHERE login_id <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reuslt = mysql_query('SELECT timestamp, headline, login_id FROM news WHERE login_id <> 1');
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['timestamp']."</td><td>".$row['headline']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```